# Matlab thinks an AVI it's written is corrupt

Tags: matlab, video

I'm using matlab to interface with a scientific camera using mex, and my matlab program uses `VideoWriter()` to write the file to disc. The camera is RGB-capable, and if I write the file as such, the video is fine. However, for the current application, I need grayscale images, and so I'm using `rgb2gray()` to convert it. Unfortunately, when the analysis code tried to read the video file again, I get the error:

```
Error using VideoReader/init (line 450)
Unable to read the file. The file appears to be corrupt.
```

and attempting to read the video with VLC confirms it to be corrupt. The only difference in my code between they grayscale and colour versions is the line:

```
frame = rgb2gray(frame);
```

My whole writing section of code is:

```
vid = VideoWriter('testVid.avi');
vid.FrameRate = framerate;
vid.Quality = 100;
open(vid);
for i = 1 : frames;
    %read frame data into variable 'frame'
    frame = rgb2gray(frame);
    writeVideo(vid,frame);
end
```

I've spent far too long fighting with this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close the video object, using `close(vid)` after writing the last frame.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work. Though quite why it works without it if I'm writing a colour video and not for a grayscale one I have no idea...

Comment: When opening a video file a header with some default values is created. When closing these values are filled. Probably these default values don't match a grayscale video so it fails.